# Django Object Get on Decimal Match

Tags: mysql, django, object, get, decimal

I have a Django model WalletJournal which has a number of fields that are Decimal values, and example model class definition looks like:

```
balance  = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2)
```

The corresponding mysql column is defined as:

```
`balance` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,
```

And when retrieving a row by its id and returning the balance it looks correct.

```
>>> WalletJournal.objects.get(id=855).balance
Decimal('1295599062.45')
>>>
```

I am attempting to use a get_or_create to add entries and keep the duplicates to a minimum, but I am seeing some very stange behaviour on the get on decimals. Trying to match view either string or Decimal returns no results:

```
>>> WalletJournal.objects.get(balance='1295599062.45')
DoesNotExist: WalletJournal matching query does not exist.
>>> WalletJournal.objects.get(balance=Decimal(str('1295599062.45')))
DoesNotExist: WalletJournal matching query does not exist.
```

But if I match using `__iexact` I get the correct result:

```
>>> WalletJournal.objects.get(balance__iexact='1295599062.45')
<WalletJournal: joeb - 1XXXX00 - Acyclic Tau(9XXXX307) - Repair Bill(2013-11-30 15:55:01)>
```

I don't believe __iexact is not a perfect solution, if somebody could suggest what I am doing wrong that would be very helpful.

I am currently running Django 1.6 and Python 2.6.5. MySQL Server version: 5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Using `connection.queries` I can see the following queries results from the various get statements:

```
__iexact       --> `balance` LIKE '1295599062.45' : Matches
__exact        --> `balance` = '1295599062.45'    : No Match
str            --> `balance` = '1295599062.45'    : No Match
Decimal(str(   --> `balance` = '1295599062.45'    : No Match
Raw SQL        --> `balance` = 1295599062.45      : Matches
```

Am I doing something wrong with the comparison?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL Server version: 5.1.72-0ubuntu0.10.04.1

Comment: Have the values of max_digits and decimal_places changed? Also, what is the value of sql_mode? I was looking through http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-expressions.html to see if something funky would take place but I don't see conditions under which that would happen yet.

Comment: You can view generated SQL (using connection.queries) to figure out why SQL ILIKE fetches the result.

Comment: I have updated the question with the results, this looks to be because the query is being constructed with the value escaped using `'` by django. Now I don't know if this is a Django issue or a MySQL issue :)

Comment: @SimeonVisser both GLOBAL.sql_mode and SESSION.sql_mode are blank as returned using `cursor.execute("SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;")` inside `python manage.py shell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a bug in the query handling of mysql. I have now tested it successfully in `Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)` and the query

```
 WalletJournal.objects.get(balance='1295599062.45')
```

Now returns results as expected with the query being executed having the following where statement:

```
`balance` = '1295599062.45'
```